# How can I put this MASSIVE excel spreadsheet as an appendix in word?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I am writing a math report and in it I need to include appendices, the only issue is that two of them are *absolutely massive* excel spreadsheets with over 2000 rows each that would just not be practical to insert/paste into my word document. Is there any way around this? I was thinking perhaps some sort of link to the spreadsheet in the appendix list but that might not work as everything needs to be contained in one file and be able to be sent to others and submitted as a single document. Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Word document, go to `Insert` > `Object` then on the Object dialog choose the `Create from File` tab. Browse your Excel file, tick both `Link to file` and `Display as icon` checkboxes, then click OK.

If the Excel file is too big, and the Word document ends up being 100's of MB, you may wish to zip up the Excel document and insert that instead. You should add a note before the object advising the user of what steps to take.

Comment: Zipping an Excel file won't reduce the size much, as the .xlsx format is already zipped.

Comment: @Paul I just created a 100MB XLSX with a bunch of random numbers, and zipped it up with 7Zip as a regular 33MB `.zip`. As an ultra-compressed `.7z` file, it's 6.6MB.

Comment: I did the same and I got a 3% gain using 7Zip with all default settings. Ultra and .7z is a lot better (80% reduction) but I wouldn't advise sending a .7z file if you don't know that the recipient can deal with it.

Comment: We're digressing.